# How can I get Windows 10 to stop prompting me about opening image files?

Tags: windows-10, security

Recently I noticed a change when using Skype. If the person I am typing with drops me a picture (typically a screenshot of a problem they are having), Windows gets all warny at me:

[image]

It happens for any kind of image file. This started happening in the last month or two and it happens in other contexts, too, but Skype is the easiest for me to reproduce to get a picture of it. It's SO annoying!

Here is another time that it happens. I am composing an email. I drag a file **from my own local machine that is fully unblocked and that I can open without prompts** onto the message so it becomes an attachment. Moments later, I double-click the image in the attachment list to double check I am sending the right file. I get the prompt then too. Interestingly, if I do the same with a **non-image** attachment, such as a PDF, I do not get a prompt. This suggests it's not (entirely anyway) about what folder the file is in, but specifically about image files.

Any error message that people just click OK on right away is a bad error message, and this fits that bill. How can I tell Windows 10 to stop it? Unchecking the checkbox doesn't help because it's "this file" not "this type of file".

Comment: Right click on that image, do you see any unlock check box?

Comment: that would only unblock **that one file**. I want the prompting to stop. For all image files ever,

Comment: Then select all the images and right click on them.

Comment: @KateGregory - Have an Administrator change your intranet security settings.

Comment: I am the closest I have to an admin. I did not change this setting, it changed itself, presumably during some update or another. It does not make me feel protected. I don't want to consent to all jpg and png and gif files forever, especially since my browsers, twitter client etc all open them without checking with me first.

Comment: @Biswa what impact will that have on the next image I get from a Skype chat, say tomorrow? Obviously it is less work to click OK on one dialog once per image, than to navigate to the file, right click, and choose an option. What I want to is to do something NOW that will mean I don't get this prompt IN FUTURE for files I have not yet received.

Comment: This is a security feature so do not mess with that just accustomed with it.

Comment: Skype is definitely a potential virus vector (so this behavior is probably a good idea to leave), based on past issues, but I think the "problem" here is that the roaming/skype folder is a "magic folder" in the "internet zone". You might look into ways to change this: look for inter/intranet trusted folder, possibly in the internet options in the control panel.

Comment: Sorry Kate, I was reading the question from my phone, I need to revise the questions I asked in the previous comment. Are you an actual administrator (permissions wise) on the computer that you are using? And just to rule out anything else strange, are you on a computer affected by group policy?

Comment: yes, I am admin (can elevate) and no, we don't have group policy.

Comment: And if you were to navigate to Windows Defender Security Center (check the icons in the bottom right tray for the shield, right click and open), then to the app & browser control icon which just looks like an empty dialog box, do any of the radio buttons in the following section say "Block"?

Comment: It makes sense to me that the Creators Update (which was April to May timeframe), or version 1703, affected your SmartScreen settings. Things that come into play are your default apps such as, in this case, your email, browser, and photo viewing apps. You shouldn't be prompted by this security warning if, after you've unchecked the box or altered the SmartScreen settings, you actually have rights to that folder / location that the photos are being stored.

Comment: Appreciate the help, other @Kate, but I have Defender not Defender Security Settings and my SmartScreen settings consist in their entirety of "warn about unrecognized apps" vs "turn smart screen off"

Comment: Okay, well I asked about group policy earlier because it sounded like the open file security warning only seemed to occur when you were opening images that reside in the C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming file. Even though your attached image is located in a trusted location prior to attachment, when you reopen the image from the email you will find that the file path changes to C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming correct? As mentioned above, check your group policy or local intranet settings that govern this.

Comment: Look at autohotkey automation. You can set it to detect this window and immediately get rid of it